# Jetpack Compose item list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

When I select item inside LazyColumn and navigate to this item I can interact with other items from previous screen(item list). Any ideas?

**LazyColumn**

```
 LazyColumn {
                val postList = homeViewModel.state.postList.value
                postList?.let {
                    items(it) { post ->
                        PostL(
                            onPostClick = { navigateToPostDetails(post) },
                            post
                        )
                    }
    
                }
            }
```

**navigateToPostDetails**

```
  fun navigateToPostDetails(post: Post) {
        val postJson = Gson().toJson(post)
        appNavController.navigate("postDetails/$postJson")
    }
```

Comment: Please add more details to describe what you want to achieve. May be with some code attached.

Comment: So, I have one screen with this list and one screen with item details. When I click on item in list, it navigates to item details screen. When I'm inside item details screen I can interact with other items in List screen. It looks like 2 screens active in one time. I need to know what causes it.

Comment: How do you interact with the other screen? Is it visible after navigating to the details screen?

Comment: When I delete background modifier, it is.

Comment: @pat20036 Post your code. *I can interact with other items in List screen* depends on your code.

Comment: Post edited with code.